# Shopify Add Text To Product Title If Color Variation Available

Tags: shopify

I have a **shopify** store and I'm trying to add something like

"If a product has color variations available then add "More Colors Available" under the title"

And if it doesn't have multiple colors available then don't add anything.

Kind of like this: http://www.jcrew.com/mens_category/pants.jsp

Answer (score 0):

Add this under the title, or wherever you want the notice to appear:

```
{% if product.options.size > 1 %}
<p>More Colors Available</p>
{% endif %}
```